# TypeORM: Extract latest value with groupBy clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, typeorm

These are my table entries:

```
id   bal    total  trans_date
1    200    220    2020-11-11
2    220    250    2020-11-11
3    250    226    2020-11-11
4    226    280    2020-11-10
```

Now, I am ordering and grouping data by transaction date

If I want to extract `newest value of total`, how can I do that ?

Ex. I want to get `total: 226` for `date 2020-11-11`

(When transaction dates are same, I am using ID to identify older and newer values)

```
await connection.manager.createQueryBuilder(RefTransaction, 'rt')
                .addSelect('rt.bal', 'balance')
                .addSelect('rt.total', 'total')
                .orderBy("rt.transDate")
                .groupBy('rt.transDate')
                .getRawMany()
```

Current Result :

```
bal  total  trans_date
200  220    2020-11-11
226  280    2020-11-10
```

Expected Result :

```
bal  total  trans_date
200  226    2020-11-11
226  280    2020-11-10
```

How should I modify my query to achieve the values ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure I follow your expected result? `200 - 226 - 2020-11-11` ?  why 200 and why 226 ? is it not `250 250` ?

Comment: I dont want MAX values @Rippo, I need the value from last record

Comment: Still unclear, @Keval why bal 200? 200 is either the first row Id=1 or the least value? You have made 226 clear as it is the last record Id=3